# PHP Error: Class::__toString() must return a string value in

Tags: php, oop, tostring

This is a `__toString()` method I'm trying to use in a PHP class. It throws the error "Catchable fatal error: Method Project::__toString() must return a string value in..."

But as far as I can tell, everything I'm passing it is a string. I even checked the `$this->proj_id` with `gettype($var)` to confirm it's a string, and it is.

Here is the Project class...

```
class Project {
  public $proj_id;
  public $proj_num;
  public $proj_name;

  public function __construct($id, $num, $name){
    $this->proj_id = $id;
    $this->proj_num = $num;
    $this->proj_name = $name;
  }

  public function __toString(){
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>".'proj_id: '."</td><td> ".$this->proj_id." </td><t/r>";
    echo "</table><br><br>";
  }
}
```

And here is the object instantiation...

```
$test_obj = new Project('XC2344','HKSTEST','Test Project');
echo $test_obj; //this is where the error shows up - even though it actually outputs the table with the correct value in both cells ?!
```

It actually outputs the table and cells and values in those cells just as I want it to, but then gives the error and stops creating the rest of the webpage.  I don't get it.

Comment: `return` !== `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__toString()` must **return** a string, not `echo` it:

```
public function __toString(){
    return "<table>"
          . "<tr><td>".'proj_id: '."</td><td> ". $this->proj_id. " </td><t/r>"
          . "</table><br><br>"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you call echo on your Project object, the object is transformed into a string which will be used for outputting. If you define __toString method by yourself, it has to return a string that has to be outputted. Instead of outputting string right away in the __toString method, just return it.

```
public function __toString(){
    return "<table>" .
           "<tr><td>".'proj_id: '."</td><td> ".$this->proj_id." </td><t/r>" .
           "</table><br><br>";
}
```

So when you call

```
echo $test_obj;
```

The __toString will be called, your function will return the  string, and echo will output it.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing is not the only use of a string. Maybe you want to save the object to a database, or put it into a JSON structure.

`__toString` must **return** a string, not output content.

```
  public function __toString(){
    $str = "<table>";
    $str .= "<tr><td>".'proj_id: '."</td><td> ".$this->proj_id." </td><t/r>";
    $str .= "</table><br><br>";

    return $str;
  }
```